Iterating through dictionary.items() seems to add foreign values to the dictionary
A simulated SevenSegment display for an LED-Matrix consist of seven virtual Segments. Though a single Segment is an object of its own class, it's basically just a dictionary storing pixel coordinates (key=screen_row type:int value=screen_columns type:list). The class SevenSegment has a method to display digits. To do that it needs to get all pixels for all segments that are needed to display the specific digit. This is done by .get_digit_pixels(digit). On the first method call it works just fine, but every further digit has artifacts of the previously called digit. This seems to be due to the dictionaries 'randomly' appending wrong values when .items() is called, though there is no command appending / storing information on those dictionaries.
Here's an abbreviated code section that reproduces the problem.
class Segment:
    def __init__(self, segment_id):
        self.id = segment_id
        self.pixels = {}  # relative pixels within segment


class SevenSegment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segment_2 = Segment(2)  # top right vertical segment
        self.segment_3 = Segment(3)  # middle horizontal segment
        self.segment_2.pixels = {4: [4, 5], }  # key=row, value=column. {0: [0, 1]} -> pixels ((0, 0), (0, 1))
        self.segment_3.pixels = {4: [1, 2, 3, 4], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], }
        self.segments = [self.segment_2, self.segment_3]
        self.digits = {1: [2], 3: [2, 3], }  # key=digit value=segment_ids of segments needed to display digit

    def get_segment_by_id(self, segment_id):
        return [segment for segment in self.segments if segment.id == segment_id][0]

    def get_digit_pixels(self, digit):
        segments = [self.get_segment_by_id(s_id) for s_id in self.digits.get(digit)]
        digit_pixels = {}
        for segment in segments:
            for row, columns in segment.pixels.items():
                if digit_pixels.get(row) is not None:
                    digit_pixels[row] += columns
                else:
                    digit_pixels[row] = columns
        for row, columns in digit_pixels.items():
            digit_pixels[row] = list(set(columns))
        return digit_pixels


# Example that shows artifacts
sevseg = SevenSegment()
print(f"Digit: {1}. Expected output on row 4: [4, 5]. Output on row 4: {sevseg.get_digit_pixels(1).get(4)}.")
print(f"Digit: {3}. Expected output on row 4: [1, 2, 3, 4]. Output on row 4: {sevseg.get_digit_pixels(3).get(4)}.")
print(f"Digit: {1}. Expected output on row 4: [4, 5]. Output on row 4: {sevseg.get_digit_pixels(1).get(4)}.")

Output:
# Digit: 1. Expected output on row 4: [4, 5]. Output on row 4: [4, 5].
# Digit: 3. Expected output on row 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Output on row 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
# Digit: 1. Expected output on row 4: [4, 5]. Output on row 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

It doesn't make sense to me and I feel stupid for being in a fundamental confusion about how dictionaries work. Although the problem could be solved by using another way of organizing the pixel coordinates, e.g. storing them in tuples instead of dictionaries, I would really appreciate some enlightenment on the dictionary part here.
Though it seems somewhat random which digit leaves which artifacts on the following digit, the added artifacts seem to always be the same for the same sequence of digits. Also artifacts are adding up: The more Segments are sequentially activated, the more artifacts show. Artifacts seem to be added to the following digit if the previous and the following digit share a row of active pixels.
These effects can be studied more thoroughly with the complete coordinates:
class SevenSegment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segment_1 = Segment(1)  # top horizontal segment
        self.segment_2 = Segment(2)  # top right vertical segment
        self.segment_3 = Segment(3)  # middle horizontal segment
        self.segment_4 = Segment(4)  # bottom right vertical segment
        self.segment_5 = Segment(5)  # bottom horizontal segment
        self.segment_6 = Segment(6)  # bottom left vertical segment
        self.segment_7 = Segment(7)  # top left vertical segment
        
        self.segment_1.pixels = {
            0: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        }
        self.segment_2.pixels = {
            0: [4, ],
            1: [4, 5],
            2: [4, 5],
            3: [4, 5],
            4: [4, 5],
        }
        self.segment_3.pixels = {
            4: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            6: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        }
        self.segment_4.pixels = {
            5: [5, ],
            6: [4, 5],
            7: [4, 5],
            8: [4, 5],
            9: [4, 5],
            10: [4, ],
        }
        self.segment_5.pixels = {
            9: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            10: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        }
        self.segment_6.pixels = {
            5: [0, ],
            6: [0, 1],
            7: [0, 1],
            8: [0, 1],
            9: [0, 1],
            10: [1, ],
        }
        self.segment_7.pixels = {
            0: [1, ],
            1: [0, 1],
            2: [0, 1],
            3: [0, 1],
            4: [0, 1],
        }
        self.segments = [self.segment_1, self.segment_2, self.segment_3, self.segment_4, self.segment_5, self.segment_6,
                         self.segment_7]
        self.digits = {  # key=digit value=segment_ids of which the digit consists
            0: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            1: [2, 4],
            2: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6],
            3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            4: [7, 3, 2, 4],
            5: [1, 7, 3, 4, 5],
            6: [1, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            7: [1, 2, 4],
            8: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
        }


Can you explain your expected output for digit 3?  If you use columns.copy() instead of columns when building digit_pixels[row], you result for Digit 1is the same both times.

@ScottHunter digit 3 should output [1, 2, 3, 4] on the key 4 because it was defined in self.segment_3.pixels = {4: [1, 2, 3, 4], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], }. The column pixel 5 that is appended in the actual output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] seems to be an artifact of digit 1 which has an active column 5 pixel on row 4 self.segment_2.pixels = {4: [4, 5], }

@ScottHunter nevermind! You're right, i made a mistake on the expectation for digit 3. Output for digit 3 should actually be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] because digit 3 activates self.segment_2 and self.segment_3 as seen in self.digits = {1: [2], 3: [2, 3], }. I'll edit the question to correct the expectation. Your comment would qualify for a solution if you could also explain why the error occurs and why .copy() is needed in this scenario, which I still don't understand.
